# elementary properties of cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials

How can one rewrite $1+x^2+x^4+x^8+\cdots x^{2^n}$ as a product of cyclotomic polynomials? more general how can we express $1+x^p+\cdots+x^{p^n}$, where $p$ is a prime, in term of  product of cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? What kind of expression are you looking for? Is there a reason to believe that such an expression should exist?

Comment: @BigM So then you would be wishing to show that such functions are a product of cyclotomic polynomials? (You should edit your question to add this if that's your intention)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was trying to show that all the roots of such polynomials lie inside the unit disk (which actually seems to be false)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be false. WolframAlpha says that $1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^8$ has roots outside the unit disk (and so can't be a product of cyclotomic polynomials).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yeah sad but true

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=1+x^2+x^4+x^6...+x^{2n}$. Assume that $n>1$, otherwise when $n=1$, $p(x)=x^2+1$, which is the only irreducible polynomial in this case. The case that $n$ is even, $p(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^n)(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^n)$. When $n$ is odd, the best possible factorization is $p(x)=(x^2+1)(1+x^4+x^8+x^{4k})$ where $2k+1=n$.

Comment: The exponents run on powers of 2 and not just all even numbers.

Comment: $x^2+1$ and $x^4+x^2+1$ factor into cyclotomic polynomials, in general, if the highest degree of the polynomial is $2^{n-1}$, then both the $n$th and $2n$th cyclotomic polyomials will be factors if $n$ is prime.